# Confusion regarding Hidden Markov Model and Conditional Random Fields

Tags: hidden, hidden-markov-models

I am a bit confused  about Hidden Markov Models and Conditional Random Fields. I wanna know id they are supervised or un-supervised learning methods?
Thanks

Comment: This might get more interesting answers in the maths or AI stacks.

Comment: Can you give me a link to a maths or AI stacks?

Comment: Pull down the menu at top left of this page.  Choose the 'all sites' button.  Et voila.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as I read several papers, they are both supervised methods and they need a labeled training set to be trained on.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.  They're models for the underlying representation of knowledge.  What happens during training is that certain transitions, being reinforced, become higher probability.

Comment: Well do I need a labeled training set?

Comment: I have a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015009/hidden-markov-model-training-for-dynamic-gestures) problem. Did you find any help @Hossein ?